# Where to store logs in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-rds

Just want to preface this post with mentioning that I'm new to software development and AWS.

I'm building a web app, and I want to keep track of every time a specific user logs into the application. I'm using Cognito for authentication and from my understanding user login times aren't stored anywhere on AWS so I'm just sending a post request when a user logs in sending the users username and the current time and storing that in a database. This is what I expect the table to look like.

.[image]

My question is what database should I use and why? I know I could use DynamoDB, RDS or and S3 bucket, but I'm not sure which one would be most ideal for this scenario.

The login times will be presented on a page of the application specific to each user. So for example when jane doe logs in she'll see 3 previous login times on a /previousactivity page or something

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: The login times will be presented on a page of the application specific to each user. So for example when jane doe logs in she'll see 3 previous login times on a /previousactivity page or something

Comment: Do you already have a database for your application?

Comment: See [Advanced Security Features](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-new-advanced-security-features-for-amazon-cognito-user-pools/) and the [AdminListUserAuthEvents API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminListUserAuthEvents.html).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Maurice's answer, here's some further background information:

In general, if you want to send logs somewhere, [CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html) is probably the service you want to use. You could use [Cognito with Lambda Triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html) to log such kind of events. This means you write a Lambda function that is just writing the data to CloudWatch Logs.

If you use [Simple Storage Service (S3)](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) to store your logs, then this is similar to what you might know from having log files that are written locally and "backed up" to S3. You can then further archive the files or create separate backups in different AWS region(s) or accounts. This scenario is more likely to be used in a setup with EC2/ECS (but also from here you can send your logs to services like CloudWatch Logs). You usually wouldn't create a log file in a Lambda function and send it to S3.

That was the general case. Now considering your current situation, you not only want to store some *logs* but rather semi-structured information. That's why Maurice's suggestion perfectly fits for your use case. It is also a cheap setup if you're using [DynamoDB with on-demand capacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html#HowItWorks.OnDemand).

Answer (score 2):

The services you mentioned are not all databases:

- **RDS** - a service that manages relational databases
- **DynamoDB** - a fully managed NoSQL database
- **S3** - object storage

Since your data model is fairly simple I'd create a DynamoDB table like this:

| PK (Partition Key) | SK (Sort Key) |
| --- | --- |
| johndoe | 2020-03-01T09:00:00Z |
| johndoe | 2020-02-01T09:00:00Z |
| johndoe | 2020-01-15T09:00:00Z |
| janedoe | 2019-03-01T09:00:00Z |
| janedoe | 2019-02-01T09:00:00Z |
| janedoe | 2019-01-15T09:00:00Z |

You can do a [query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) on the partition key and will get all login times for the given user in byte-order, that's why it's important to normalize the datetime information. You can use the `Limit` parameter to limit how many results you're interested in and `ScanIndexForward` to specify the order.

If you want to delete older logins, you can either use the Time to live functionality of a DynamoDB table or whenever you log in, you remove older items.